# Drawing animate line on Canvas of a View

Tags: android, jquery-animate, android-canvas

I simply need to draw a line which moves from one coordinate of a canvas to another. I am having troubles with synchronizing my drawing code with time.\

```
public class CustomMYChart extends View {

float x=0,y=0;
Canvas canvas;
Paint paint;

public CustomMYChart(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);        

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.canvas=canvas;

    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){

        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 5, paint);
        x+=1;
        y+=1;
        invalidate();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: what do you want to do with 1000 loops?

Comment: this is a sample code but I thought providing 1000 loops will make it draw smoother lines

Comment: then, what is your problem with this code?

Comment: I am not able to apply animation to this drawing, I tried using timertask but that doesn't draw on the view of the canvas

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the for statement in onDraw, with just one for iteration you call 1000 times invalidate() and then you get x and y out of the screen.

```
  @Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.canvas=canvas;



        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 5, paint);
        x+=1;
        y+=1;
        invalidate();
    }
```